# Hide header with google groups inside UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, google-groups

I'm displaying google groups view inside my UIWebView window but it displays the header with options to other google services. Is there a way to hide the header and just display the google groups content ?

This is the URL I'm using ...

```
https://groups.google.com/d/forum/MyAppGroupName
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UIWebViewDelegate method webViewDidFinishLoad and run this JS script in

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
NSString *script = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById(\"og_head\").style.display='none';"];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];
}
```